# How do I enter the variable value of my bash command into MySQL?

Tags: mysql, bash, httrack

The following code extracts all the domain names from a website and sets them to the value of `$domain` from a `httrack` data stream.

```
domain=$(httrack --skeleton http://www.ilovefreestuff.com -V "cat \$0" | grep -iEo '[[:alnum:]-]+\.(com|net|org)')
```

The value of $domain looks like this...

> googlesyndication.com facebook.com facebook.com ilovefreestuff.com
>   ilovefreestuff.com facebook.com facebook.com ilovefreestuff.com
>   ilovefreestuff.com peadig.com facebook.net ilovefreestuff.com w3.org
>   ilovefreestuff.com yoast.com ilovefreestuff.com

I have my database setup and this command works perfectly.

```
mysql -pPASSWORD -e "INSERT INTO domains.domains (domains) VALUES ($domain)”
```

I’m trying to insert each individual domain within the variable `$domain` into my MySQL database on the fly from the `httrack` data stream within one combined command line. So in my crazy mind it should look something similar to below… Unfortunately this doesn’t work. I get no output, just another bash prompt.

```
domain=$(httrack --skeleton http://www.ilovefreestuff.com -V "cat \$0" | grep -iEo '[[:alnum:]-]+\.(com|net|org)') | mysql -pPASSWORD -e "INSERT INTO domains.domains (domains) VALUES ($domain)"
```

I’m not sure how to cut up the `$domain` variable into individual domains so I can enter one domain per MySQL data cell, and I’m not certain how to pipe the result to MySQL given that the command is a data stream. Maybe I need a for loop and a cut command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Maybe I need a for loop and a cut command?

You said it. It won’t be a one-liner but this should work:

```
domain=$(httrack --skeleton http://www.ilovefreestuff.com -V "cat \$0" | grep -iEo '[[:alnum:]-]+\.(com|net|org)')

for single_domain in $domain
do
  mysql -pPASSWORD -e "INSERT INTO domains.domains (domains) VALUES ($single_domain)"
done
```

Comment: Yes, this work.  The problem with this solution is the httrack data stream is very large and the httrack command could possibly run for hours and/or days on some websites.  Sometimes it never completes.  Therefore I was hoping to import the domains as it discovers them in real time.  Is there a better way for me to complete my desired result?

Comment: Yes this is the solution I'm looking for.

Comment: FWIW: can be written in one line, too ;-)

Comment: This was my initial solution as I simply dumped the result to a text file.  Unfortunately, I received so much data mostly in the form of duplicate domains that it was difficult to sort/unique.  Some of these text files were 50GB or more.  Therefore my solution was to setup a mysql database with a unique cell and import on the fly so I wouldn't have to deal with so much data.  However, I guess I could simply import my data from txt file into a unique mysql data cell after httrack is complete to remove duplicates.